# The above code is working fine for both chrome and firefox. But in IE this does not give save pop up box! What should I do to support this code ??

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, png

At first, add the generated dataURL to the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag.
On some browsers, this alone will not trigger a download, but open the linked image in a new page.

**Download dialog for a base64 image:**

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...." class="image" />
```

Based on above example, convert the MIME type of the DataURL to this:

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg....">Download</a>
```

Telling the browser that the data is `application/octet-stream`, it will ask you to save it on your hard-disk.

---

**Specifying a filename:**

As Adnan said in the comments below (@Adnan: I upvoted yours as this is actually a big problem): There is no standard way to define a filename using this method, but there are two approaches which might work in some browsers.

A) The download-attribute

```
<a download="image.png" href="...">
```

(Introduced by Google Crome)

B) Defining HTTP-headers within the data-URL
`headers=Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.png`

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename=image.png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA">
```

(Worked at least in some older versions of Opera)
[Here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2010Feb/0069.html) is some discussion about this.

Looking into the Bug/Feature-Tracking systems of the major browsers shows that defining a filename is a quite big wish of the community. Maybe we will see a cross-browser compatible solution in near future! ;)

---

**Save RAM and CPU ressources:**

If you don't want to bloat the RAM of your visitor's browser, you can also generate the data-URL dynamically:

```
<a id="dl" download="Canvas.png">Download Canvas</a>
```

```
function dlCanvas() {
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    this.href = dt;
};
dl.addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

This way, your canvas may still be shown as an image file by your browser.
If you want to increase the probability to open a download dialog, you should extend the function above, so that it does the replacement as shown above:

```
function dlCanvas() {
    var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    this.href = dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
};
dl.addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

At last, you could even add the HTTP-header to make extra shure that most browser offer a valid filename to you! ;)

---

**FULL EXAMPLE:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

/* FILL CANVAS WITH IMAGE DATA */
function r(ctx, x, y, w, h, c) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.strokeStyle = c;
  ctx.stroke();
}
r(ctx, 0, 0, 32, 32, "black");
r(ctx, 4, 4, 16, 16, "red");
r(ctx, 8, 8, 16, 16, "green");
r(ctx, 12, 12, 16, 16, "blue");

/* REGISTER DOWNLOAD HANDLER */
/* Only convert the canvas to Data URL when the user clicks. 
   This saves RAM and CPU ressources in case this feature is not required. */
function dlCanvas() {
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  /* Change MIME type to trick the browser to downlaod the file instead of displaying it */
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]*/, 'data:application/octet-stream');

  /* In addition to <a>'s "download" attribute, you can define HTTP-style headers */
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:application\/octet-stream/, 'data:application/octet-stream;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename=Canvas.png');

  this.href = dt;
};
document.getElementById("dl").addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="32" height="32"></canvas>
<a id="dl" download="Canvas.png" href="#">Download Canvas</a>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support the `download` attribute on anchors. As a workaround, you can use Eli Grey's FileSaverJS in IE: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Answer (score -1):

I succeed with this approach.

Basically you use this.
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Then generate blob data from base64 string.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript

I close this issue because there is alternative way.

You can use above github as a reference. U will get a good idea about it

Comment: The links itself are not the answer.  You should elaborate.